# Marlin 2.1.x Cannot build code using Platformio in VScode

Tags: embedded, platformio

I have been at a total loss at to why this Marlin 2.1.x for Tronxy x5SA pro will not build. I have discovered that by the looks of things I am not the only individual suffering this problem. I have updatec VScode and platformio but to no avail. On examining the out put from the build and then examining the following file marlin.py I have found that it appears that there are no path references to SCon scripts. There is also a further issue that there does not appear to be any reference to macros defined in macros.h resulting in a large number of errors.

build output:

### Resolving chitu_f103 dependencies...
Already up-to-date.
Updating metadata for the vscode IDE...
UserSideException: Processing chitu_f103 (platform: ststm32@~12.1; board: marlin_CHITU_F103; framework: arduino)

Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/ststm32/marlin_CHITU_F103.html
PLATFORM: ST STM32 (12.1.1) > CHITU STM32F103Z (64k RAM. 512k Flash)
HARDWARE: STM32F103ZET6 72MHz, 59.12KB RAM, 469.03KB Flash
DEBUG: Current (blackmagic) External (blackmagic, jlink, stlink)
PACKAGES:

- framework-arduinoststm32-maple @ 3.10000.201129 (1.0.0)
- tool-stm32duino @ 1.0.2
- toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi @ 1.70201.0 (7.2.1)
  Converting Marlin.ino
  LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> URL bit.ly/configure-pio-ldf
  LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
  Found 27 compatible libraries
  Scanning dependencies...
  Dependency Graph
  |-- SoftwareSerialM @ 1.0.0
  |-- STM32ADC @ 1.0
  |-- EEPROM
  |-- USBComposite for STM32F1 @ 0.99
  |-- Wire @ 1.0
  |-- Servo(STM32F1) @ 1.1.2
  Building in release mode
  RuntimeError: deque mutated during iteration:
  File "C:\Users\ahepa01.platformio\penv\Lib\site-packages\platformio\builder\main.py", line 180:
  env.SConscript(env.GetExtraScripts("post"), exports="env")
  File "C:\Users\ahepa01.platformio\packages\tool-scons\scons-local-4.5.2\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 598:
  return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "C:\Users\ahepa01.platformio\packages\tool-scons\scons-local-4.5.2\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 285:
  exec(compile(scriptdata, scriptname, 'exec'), call_stack[-1].globals)
  File "C:\Users\ahepa01\Downloads\Marlin_X5SA_Master\X5SA\buildroot\share\PlatformIO\scripts\chitu_crypt.py", line 8:
  marlin.relocate_firmware("0x08008800")
  File "C:\Users\ahepa01\Downloads\Marlin_X5SA_Master\X5SA\buildroot\share\PlatformIO\scripts\marlin.py", line 27:
  replace_define("VECT_TAB_ADDR", address)
  File "C:\Users\ahepa01\Downloads\Marlin_X5SA_Master\X5SA\buildroot\share\PlatformIO\scripts\marlin.py", line 20:
  for define in env['CPPDEFINES']:
  ========================= [FAILED] Took 19.30 seconds =========================

Environment    Status    Duration

---

chitu_f103     FAILED    00:00:19.303
==================== 1 failed, 0 succeeded in 00:00:19.303 ====================

and from platform io all project paths point to a directory called marlin in :
C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\ ?  Marlin does not exist.

There is another reference to the same problem but it is not the answer to my issue.

I have installed SCon python package. I have updated system paths to include those missing packages I have tried different variations of the Merlin source but to no avail. In the past building Marlin using arduino IDE was a breeze. I also have previously built Marlin about 2 years ago using VSCode and PlatformIO successfully. But this current set of sources do not compile. And I think the problem is down to the paths that are used to build the application.

CAN anyone help to resolve this issue?